# Flutter dependency image_picker causing app error when launching

Tags: flutter

I am trying to install the package image_picker from pub.dev into my Flutter project, but when launching the app, it causes an error:

```
[+14087 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
[        ] > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
[        ]    > Problems reading data from Binary store in /private/var/folders/4w/fdcbgwhs6q796kh0_rn5f9l00000gn/T/gradle6792228913679833550.bin offset 302541 exists? true
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 23s
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"b171000b-0966-40c7-8c91-6fe591ee7282","id":"0","progressId":null,"finished":true}}]
[ +415 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +5 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:474:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #19     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #20     AndroidDevice.isLocalEmulator (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
           #21     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #22     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #23     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #26     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #27     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #34     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #35     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

The error must be caused by this dependency, because removing it from pubspec.yaml makes the project launch normal, without any exceptions.

I have searching for the issue, I have change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
```

and I am getting the same issue.

I have also tested with several package versions, but always getting the same issue.

Comment: Are permissions “READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” and “WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” granted in AndroidManifest file??

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, yes they are: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Try changing in pub spec file: `image_picker: ^0.8.x+x` in `image_picker: any` then update dependencies.

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj,, let me try

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, same issue, no solution, but thank you